# VS2013RC requires IE10 but i need (not want) IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10, visual-studio-2013

I've been evaluating the VS2013preview since its release and was keen to install the RC. The problem is we need ie8 for legacy testing as many customers out in the field still use it.

As a possible workaround would it be possible to either, skip or fool the install package into thinking its installed? or install ie10 and then drop back to ie8 after installation?

I appreciate there may be some areas of things like browserlink to ie that I cannot use but this is OK as I mostly use chrome for initial dev work prior to testing in the various browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credit goes to Jimmy [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4153040-remove-the-requirment-for-internet-explorer-10-to-), but here's a hack to make it work:

```
@ECHO OFF

:IE10HACK 
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v Version /t REG_SZ /d "9.10.9200.16384" /f 
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v svcVersion /t REG_SZ /d "10.0.9200.16384" /f 
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v Version /t REG_SZ /d "9.10.9200.16384" /f 
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v svcVersion /t REG_SZ /d "10.0.9200.16384" /f 
GOTO EXIT

:REVERTIE 
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v svcVersion 
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v svcVersion 
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v Version /t REG_SZ /d "8.0.7601.17514" /f 
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v Version /t REG_SZ /d "8.0.7601.17514" /f 
GOTO EXIT

:EXIT
```

Comment: In my testing for VS 2013 RTM only svcVersion value modification required: http://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2013/10/23/fake-ie10-to-install-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: Probably late to the party, I didn't run the script but i went directly to regedit( Registry Editor) to change the Version value (for IE8) to 9.10.9200.16384 but VS still failed to identify the change. Hence, it might be worth noting I created a new string value called "svcVersion" with the value of 10.0.9200.16384, which is understandable because all IE10 have that string value.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you're trying to use the same machine for developing and testing.  Don't rely on the local copy of IE on your machine for testing a legacy browser, instead rely on virtual machine copies of Windows and run that specific browser.

If you want a quick & dirty way to test your stuff in specific versions of IE use the IETester as mentioned by others in the comments.  http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: I feel like relying on a virtual machine isn't a great answer if you aren't using current hardware. Where I work, my coworkers are stuck with some ancient machines that choke up and die if you even try to load 2 instances of Visual Studio at once. Having to run a virtual machine would slow things down considerably for them.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider simply using a virtual machine to run a copy of Windows with IE8 in it for your testing, since you don't really use it for day to day stuff anyways.

Comment: yes tried that but its not an ideal solution as it slows down the workstation and makes it more difficult to determine if the speed issues being tested are due to the vm's resources or not.

Comment: @Tim - any VM that can't handle a web browser has serious problems

Comment: testing heavy javascript pages in ie8 when rdping into a vm its difficult to tell if the speed is a graphics issue with the rdp drivers etc, also the overhead of the vm on the workstation is noticeable to the development environment, you cannot easily seperate the ie dev tools to one monitor and the browser to another etc. Thanks for the suggestions but i was rather looking for a workaround to the vs2012rc block on ie8.

Comment: @Tim - RDP does indeed work with multiple monitors, you just specify the /span command, and RDP will also support hardware acceleration, particularly if it's local on the same machine.  no VM should put any noticeable overhead on your workstation if all its doing is running a browser.  If it's that important to you, get a second computer to run IE8, or use IETester http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage.

Comment: i was really wanting help with the original query, other alternatives are possible but only if we cannot resolve the original query. Ive been using various flavours of vm's on my machine for some time so im very aware of their positives and negatives

Comment: @Tim - If you're very aware, why are you saying things that aren't true then?  Like not being able to use two monitors in an RDP session?  Regardless, It's unlikely you will find a way to do this, and even if can, I think you will run into a lot of problems and will fine that VS will become unstable because it assumes things that aren't there.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft announced yesterday that they are removing the requirement.

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4153040-remove-the-requirment-for-internet-explorer-10-to-